# Did Absalom ask David to come with him to his sheep-shearers knowing that David would say no and in return allow Amnon to go out of guilt?

Tags: samuel-shmuel-book-of

In Shmuel 2 Chapter 13, when Absalom asks David to come with him to his sheep-shearers, why does he ask King David to go with him?

Is he asking him knowing that his father would decline? or did he have plans to try to kill his father as well?

Was this part of his plan so that his father would feel guilty for rejecting to go and afterwards allow Amnon to go so that he could kill him?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gersonides explains that he invited David knowing he'd refuse. This was an attempt to get Amnon to attend (without inviting him ab initio, which would raise suspicion), so he could kill him.